# pyqt phonon video fade to color (e.g. fade to black)

Tags: python, video, phonon

I am programming a media player for "live" use (On Stages) therefor I need the ability to fade out a video (e.g. Fade to Black/Background color)

I am using pyqt4 with phonon for playing and displaying the video.

As I usually am programming webpages and this is my first qui project, I have no clue, how to do that:

My Idea: Render Video Transparent and the background behind the video is black.

My Testing code right now (Starts and generates a full screen window with full screen video player:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
from time import sleep

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.media = Phonon.MediaObject(self)
        self.video = Phonon.VideoWidget(self)

        self.setGeometry(2000,10,200,200)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)

        geometry = self.geometry()

        self.video.setMinimumSize(geometry.width(), geometry.height())
        self.audio = Phonon.AudioOutput(Phonon.VideoCategory, self)

        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.audio)
        Phonon.createPath(self.media, self.video)

        # Generate Layout inside of Window and Remove the Borders.
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.video, 0)

        self.media.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource("video.mp4"))

        self.media.play()





if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Phonon Player')
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```